# NoSQL database design for email-like web app

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm developing a web app for private messaging inspired by email services (Gmail) using AngularJS on client side and MongoDB (Mongoose) and NodeJS for RESTful server.

Currently, this is the db structure

```
{
conversation: {
    user1: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    user2: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    user1Flags: [String],
    user2Flags: [String],
    messages: [{
        title: String,
        content: String,
        sender: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
        },
        sentAt: Date,
        createdAt: Date,
        attachments: [String],
        senderMetaData: {
            archived: Boolean,
            deleted: Boolean
        },
        recipientMetaData: {
            archived: Boolean,
            deleted: Boolean
        }
    }]
}
}
```

Well, I'm satisfied with this, but I don't have too much experience with NoSql.

I want to hear your opinion on this, is this the right way to go ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not taking advantage of POP3/IMAP/SMTP protocols that have been standardized since the advent of computer networking?

Comment: This should be a small part of much more complex app and private messages aren't based on email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious performance consideration for your design is that you are storing potentially [large embedded arrays of messages](http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays) in a single conversation document. As the very active conversations grow larger, those documents will require more frequent relocations on disk and ultimately could hit the [maximum document size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) (16MB, as at MongoDB 2.6). If you only care about the recent messages in the array, you will also incur a growing overhead of loading the full document into memory on the MongoDB server even if you only project a subset of recent information via the driver call.

For some ideas on how to design an efficient messaging approach, I would suggest reading the documentation for the [Socialite](https://github.com/10gen-labs/socialite) project. This is most definitely overkill for your use case, but you might find some helpful things to consider. For example, the [`Feed Service`](https://github.com/10gen-labs/socialite/blob/master/docs/feed.md) describes several different approaches including disadvantages and suggestions on when each is more suitable.